# Resolver Undefined namespace Mailer CakePHP 3.0.3

Tags: php, cakephp, namespace, cakephp-3

Estou tentando criar um **Email Reusável** provido pelo CakePHP 3 porém mesmo seguindo o a documentação porém tenho o seguinte erro:

```
use Cake\Mailer\Mailer;
```

**Erro:**

> Undefined namespace Mailer
>
> Referenced namespace is not found.

Criei o arquivo no mesmo diretório do especificado na documentação

**OBS:** Estou usando o **CakePHP 3.0.3**

Link para a documentação: [Link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-reusable-emails)

Comment: não uso cakePHP mas eu vi ali na documentação um `use Cake\Mailer\MailerAwareTrait`

Comment: @RafaelAcioly não é possível identificar "Mailer" e ainda no exemplo que copiei fazia uso do `use Cake\Mailer\Mailer;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mailers só estarão disponiveis na versão **CakePHP 3.1** que esta atualmente em fase beta.

- **http://bakery.cakephp.org/2015/08/01/cakephp_3_1_0_beta_released.html**
- **http://bakery.cakephp.org/2015/08/05/cakephp_3_0_11_and_3_1_0_beta2_released.html**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/3.1**

Fonte: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860897/resolve-undefined-namespace-mailer-cakephp-3-0-3)

> **Entretanto é possivel um Mail através do `Namespace` `Cake\Network\Email` na versão 3.0 do CakePHP**